Why would a direct Sodium measurement read lower than a sodium measurement converted from a Chloride (as Sodium Chloride) Measurement from a lab?
I have a lab doing analysis on beverages for my company and its been challenging getting a good layman's explanation as to why the same beverage would read lower sodium on a sodium specific test versus the sodium level we could calculate out from a Chloride test.
Ex: The "Sodium" test reads a level of 2000 mg/l and the "Chloride (as Sodium Chloride)" test reports as 6.6 g/l. If I am calculating things the way I think I should, the Chloride test would indicate a Sodium level of 2,640 mg/l.
Am I missing anything in the calculation? Is there a reason the 2 would present as different levels from the same beverage if we know the Chloride comes exclusively from Sodium Chloride which is where I derived the Sodium level I did from the Chloride test?
Thanks in advance for the education. High school was a long time ago and my Chemistry skills are rusty at best

Consider other counter anions of chloride (Ca,Mg,K), BTW, it is almost sea water, roughly 2/3 of salt content of Baltic sea water.

Thanks for the comment Poutnik. Good suggestion to inquire what other chloride sources might be in the beverage that would cause us to calculate higher Sodium levels using the Chloride test results versus the levels seen in the Sodium specific test. We aren't the producer of the beverage but it is indeed, incredibly salty by design. The lab reads Chloride as a "presumed from Sodium Chloride" approach since Sodium Chloride is most commonly used in beverage versus other Chloride anions.

It is generally not good idea to have in drinks just sodium, especially in such high concentration.

For a sports drink formulated for high-intensity activities:     Sodium (Na): 500-1000 mg/L //   Potassium (K): 100-200 mg/L  //  Calcium (Ca): 20-50 mg/L //  Magnesium (Mg): 10-30 mg/L  //

Thanks for the insights Poutnik. I will be sure to share with the producer. I know the potassium and magnesium levels are currently aligned with your suggestions but their salt content is quite extreme by comparison to anything else in the market.

In analytical chemistry sometimes results are quoted in a strange way. For example in fertilizers, phosphorous content is stated as $\ce{P2O5}$ or potassium as $\ce{K2O}$. These results are due to historical reasons. Since your analysis is relevant to food industry, it is not surprising that chloride analysis is displayed as $\ce{NaCl}$. Your calculations are correct.
Second important thing is that you must ask for the standard deviation of the results. What standard deviations do the lab reports quote for each analysis? If one start worrying about only two significant figures for chloride content (6.6 g/L) then, then we cannot say exactly 2640 mg Na/L.
The common source of error is that chloride could be coming from another source as well (not associated with Na). Chloride ion is a very common impurity and so is sodium. You must be adding acidifiers and all other things including a large amount of sugar. Extra chloride can come from anywhere.

Thanks for the response ACR. Sounds like we need to try to get a little more information from the beverage maker and their flavor house regarding potential sources of additional chloride. Very helpful feedback and advise to share with our team. Cheers!
